# Using icon font in css content

Tags: css, fonts, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to use font icons with the zurb foundation [icon pack](http://zurb.com/playground/foundation-icon-fonts-3#allicons) and while of course you can display them inline via of course something as simple as;

```
<i class="fi-alert"></i>
```

Except when I try to use it as css content (which is how they display them...) I don't get the same result when I do something like `content: "\f101"` inside of a css class. I just get those squares to display.

Is the only difference that I include them externally? via;

```
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundicons/3.0.0/foundation-icons.css?hash=132456789blahblahblah" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or what? Am I just missing a src ref in my sass or something inane like that? I'm doing it just how I would expect it to work and have done with others in the past but I get no icon using them from the css, only shown inline with the html? I know it's going to be some dumb oversight so could use another pair of eyes.

Sorry, kicking the dust off my web experience, it's been awhile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `font-family` to the icon font in the same class where you set the `content`.

```
.icon:after{
  font-family: "foundation-icons";
  content: "\f101";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use them in a css selector like that you have to actually install the font-family  for your page and declare that font-family in your css selector before using the code.

This is a decent tutorial https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/how-to-use-and-embed-an-icon-font-on-your-website

Answer (score 0):

Please provide an example of code that works and doesn't work for you.

If you are trying to display icon by adding :content to an existing css element that is not part of icon pack, this will not work. For example this WILL NOT WORK:

```
HTML: <li class="icon">text </li>
CSS: .icon:before { content: "\f101"; }}
```

Use 'i' tag to add icons:

```
HTML: <li class="icon"><i class="fi-alert"></i>text </li>
```

Every time you see squares you need to check if font files are loaded. There are 4 fonts are used by icon set in case you want to load css on your server and link them manually:

- /foundation-icons.eot
- /foundation-icons.woff
- /foundation-icons.ttf
- /foundation-icons.svg